How to set ExecStart for Puma service for a Rails app (rvm)?
I am trying to properly configure the setup of my puma service, but still unsuccessfully. My nginx.conf looks like this:
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/rails/myapps/myproj/shared/tmp/sockets/myproj-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/rails/myapps/myproj/current/public;
  access_log /home/rails/myapps/myproj/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/rails/myapps/myproj/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

The file /home/rails/myapps/myproj/shared/tmp/sockets/myproj-puma.sock doesn't exist, the directory is empty.
In the myproj_puma_production.service is the following content:
[Unit]
Description=redata-app
#Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=rails
#Group=rails
#WorkingDirectory=/home/rails/myapps/myproj/
WorkingDirectory=/home/rails/myapps/myproj/
#ExecStart=/usr/share/rvm/bin/rvm all do bundle exec puma -b tcp://0.0.0.0:3000 -e production
#ExecStart=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin/bundle exec puma -C /home/rails/myapps/myproj/current/config/puma.rb
ExecStart=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin exec puma -C /home/rails/myapps/myproj/current/config/puma.rb
TimeoutSec=30s
RestartSec=30s
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

When I run systemctl --user status redata_puma_production, I get the following error referencing to the wrong ExecStart:
● myproj_puma_production.service - myproj-app
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/xdg/systemd/user/myproj_puma_production.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-04-15 16:06:43 UTC; 25s ago
    Process: 122683 ExecStart=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin exec puma -C /home/rails/myapps/myproj/current/config/puma.rb (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)
   Main PID: 122683 (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)
        CPU: 2ms

I don't know how to properly configure the ExecStart field. I tried to run which puma, but only got an empty output. puma is installed within the Rails app.
What am I missing?

Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about programming, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? for guidance.

Not sure if can help but my rails systemD service looks like this
[Unit]
Description=myapp

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/maxence/Desktop/myapp

User=maxence
Group=maxence
# ProtectProc=invisible

ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc "bin/start_app"

# Let systemd restart this service always
Restart=always

# Specifies the maximum file descriptor number that can be opened by this process
LimitNOFILE=65536

# Specifies the maximum number of threads this process can create
TasksMax=infinity

# Disable timeout logic and wait until process is stopped
TimeoutStopSec=infinity
SendSIGKILL=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Where bin/start_app just starts two foreman services. One to prepare the app and the second to run it, with two different procfiles
#!/bin/bash
foreman start -f Procfile_prepare -e .env
foreman start -f Procfile_services -e .env

Basically Puma and Sidekiq are booted through Foreman
Also my Nginx file has no upstream attribute
Regardsing your service, the working directoty is set so can you not just start rails the classic way rails s -e production ?
